# Unable to do Computed Databind

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I've written a function (Polymer 1.2.0) to return an auth header for iron-ajax, but no matter what I try, I get the message 
`[dom-bind::_annotatedComputationEffect]: compute method`makeheaders`not defined`

In addition to this code, I've also tried the `Polymer({is: 'dom-bind'} ... blah:fn()' way of binding the fn.

What am I doing wrong? Here's the relevant chunk of the code:

```
<div id="futuretweets" style="height: 400px">


    <template is="dom-bind" id="big-temp">


        <script>

            document.querySelector('template[is=dom-bind]').makeheaders = function () {
                var obj = {};
                obj.Authorization = "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem('userToken');
                return obj;
            };


        </script>

        <iron-localstorage name="auth" value="{{localtoken}}"></iron-localstorage>

        <iron-ajax url="api/twitter/v1/private/gettweets" last-response="{{data}}" auto
                   headers="{{makeheaders()}}"
                   handle-as="json">

        </iron-ajax>
        <iron-list items="[[data.futuretweets]]" as="item">
            <template id="tweet-item">
                <form is="iron-form" id="tweetform" method="post" action="api/twitter/v1/private/updatetweet"
                      headers="{{makeheaders()}}" contentType="application/json">
                    <div class="card layout horizontal center">
                        <paper-textarea label="Tweet">[[item.text]]</paper-textarea>
                        <p>datetime: [[item.datetime]]</p>
                    </div>
                    <paper-button>Save</paper-button>
                </form>
            </template>
        </iron-list>
    </template>


    <div id="tweeteditor">

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the script outside of the `template` element. Templates are static. What happens in your code is that you are declaring the `dom-bind`'s property after it was stamped to the DOM.

Comment: Thank you! I moved the script to after the template, and it worked.